# Ninject get all instances created at the moment?

Tags: c#, ninject

Is there a way to retrieve a list of IMyInterface which are already instantiated by not yet disposed?
For example:

```
public interface IMyInterface : IDisposable {} //IDisposable will be called by Ninject when object collected by GC

public class MyModule : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<IMyInterface>().To<MyImplementation>();//creates new instance on every Get<> call
    }
}

var a = kernel.Get<IMyInterface>();
var b = kernel.Get<IMyInterface>();
var c = kernel.Get<IMyInterface>();

var abcList = kernel.GetCurrentInstances<IMyInterface>(); // list contains [a,b,c] instances, because they are not collected at this point
```

Comment: This seems like an XY problem. Why would you want to do this?

Comment: I have duplex channel, one per user, server-side interface is instantiated through InTransientScope on server, so I want to broadcast some messages to them through callback, but I don't care about lifetime of those channels, this is snapshot operation, which should not reference those dependencies

Answer (score 1):

While I am not aware of a buit-in way of doing this, you could easily achieve this using `ActivationActions`. This allows you to specify functions to be executed when objects are created for a particular binding. Then you can have an `ObjectTracker<T>` class that tracks instantiations for a particular class using weak references:

```
public static class BindingExtension
{
    public static IBindingToSyntax<TInterface> TrackObjects<TInterface>(this IBindingToSyntax<TInterface> self)
        where TInterface : class
    {

        self.Kernel.Bind<ObjectTracker<TInterface>>().ToSelf().InSingletonScope();
        self.BindingConfiguration.ActivationActions.Add((c, o) =>
        {
            c.Kernel.Get<ObjectTracker<TInterface>>().Add((TInterface)o);
        });

        return self;
    }
}
// Usage
public class MyModule : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<IMyInterface>()
            .TrackObjects()
            .To<MyImplementation>();//creates new instance on every Get<> call
    }
}

var a = kernel.Get<IMyInterface>();
var b = kernel.Get<IMyInterface>();
var c = kernel.Get<IMyInterface>();

var abcList = kernel.Get<ObjectTracker<IMyInterface>>().AllInstances.ToList();

// Helper class
public class ObjectTracker<T>
    where T: class
{
    private List<WeakReference<T>> instances = new List<WeakReference<T>>();
    public void Add(T item)
    {
        this.Prune(); // You could optimize how often you prune the list, with a counter for example.
        instances.Add(new WeakReference<T>(item));
    }
    public void Prune()
    {
        this.instances.RemoveAll(x => !x.TryGetTarget(out var _));
    }
    public IEnumerable<T> AllInstances => instances
        .Select(x =>
        {
            x.TryGetTarget(out var target);
            return target;
        })
        .Where(x => x != null);
}
```

Comment: @eocron Could you be more specific ? I tested it and it worked for the example above

Comment: @eocron Note that since I used weak references, If your objects get garbage collected, they will not show up when you call `AllInstances` If you want to keep the objects alive, you can use `List<T>` instead